# Can blood vessels be weakend

Tags: blood-circulation, healing

Lets say everyday you fall off your bike and your leg starts bleeding at the same spot everytime. Do the bloodvessels at this spot get weakend and if yes, does less blood reach your foot because the bloodvessels are weakend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So blood vessels in the human transport (circulatory) system are of three types: capillaries, arteries and veins.

Capillaries: Even if you get a slight cut or scratch, capillaries will get affected.
Veins: If you get a moderate (intensity) cut or scratch on a place on the skin where veins are close, veins will get affected and you will need immediate first aid eg bandage, etc.
Arteries: If the cut is deep enough to reach arteries, then arteries will be affected and this is a pretty risky situation as high pressure blood flows through the arteries which gushes out upon rupture.

As the intensities of cuts increase, and depending on the type(s) of blood vessels affected, healing times will differ.

I don't know what you mean by 'weakened'. If this refers to permanent damage, then yes it is possible. However, in most cases, given urgent medical treatment, the affected blood vessels eventually heal.

Hope it helps.